# Grit: Show all files in master

Tags: ruby, git, grit

I'm trying to wrap my head around using Grit to write to a Git repository. I can easily create a repo and make a commit:

```
repo = Repo.init_bare("grit.git")
index = Index.new(repo)
index.add('myfile.txt', 'This is the content')
index.commit('first commit')
```

I can also easily make the second commit, using the first commit as parent:

```
index.add('myotherfile.txt', 'This is some other content')
index.commit("second commit", [repo.commits.first])
```

But now how do I get the content of those 2 files without traversing through the entire commit history? Isn't there a smarter way for me to get the current state of the files in a repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(repo.tree / 'myfile.txt').data
```

Specifically, the [tree](http://grit.rubyforge.org/classes/Grit/Repo.html#M000232) method (which can take any commit, but defaults to master) returns a [Tree](http://grit.rubyforge.org/classes/Grit/Tree.html).  Tree has a convenient [/](http://grit.rubyforge.org/classes/Grit/Tree.html#M000276) method which returns a [Blob](http://grit.rubyforge.org/classes/Grit/Blob.html) or Tree depending what filename you pass in.  Finally, Blob has a [data](http://grit.rubyforge.org/classes/Grit/Blob.html#M000264) method that returns the exact data.

EDIT: If you want a list of all the filenames in the repo (which may be an expensive operation), one way is:

```
all_files = repo.status.map { |stat_file| stat_file.path }
```

This assumes everything is tracked.  If you're not sure, you can filter on the `untracked` attribute.

Comment: But what if I don't know what my file names are? What if it is a repo with 1000 files? Is there a way to do something like repo.tree.all?

Comment: Thanks! I think my problem was that I didn't call read_tree on the index before committing the second time (it was in another controller)